# org-agenda-skip-function not working

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Just recently, I made some changes to my org configuration as I had been making some changes in my daily work framework. That broke a part of my configuration.

```
(tags-todo "School"
                        ((org-agenda-skip-fuction '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled))
                         (org-agenda-overriding-header "School Work for today: ")))
```

Particularly, agenda entries which are scheduled are not being skipped. A typical such entry is as follows:

```
** TODO Make weekly test papers for next week, classes 9-12, for Maths, Sci etc.
   SCHEDULED: <2010-10-09 Sat +1w>
```

Earlier after a lot of effort, I had created a regular expression check which used to skip such entries. Of course, org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled is much better than that.

I know c#, but no lisp as such. Kindly help.

Comment: I suggest you post this question to the orgmode mailing list - you'll probably get an answer in minutes.

Comment: Actually, I did. I didn't get any reply there. So came here. Don't really know what is the problem with my question that it is not generating any reply?! :(

Comment: If this is done in the context of `org-agenda-custom-commands`, post the complete definition.

Comment: 7 years later I'm dealing with exactly the same problem. Any hint ?

Comment: It looks like (org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled) skips entries which are marked as 'Scheduled: ' in the agenda view and not hose who have the 'SCHEDULED: <...>' cookie. That is if a task is scheduled in a month from now, it will not be filtered out as it doesn't appears as scheduled in the current week's agenda.

Comment: Ahhh ... the documentation is a little bit ambiguous. The description "... the entry (i.e. the text before the next heading) is checked." refers to the text in the agenda view. So in our case org-agenda-skip-subtree-if function should be used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Super-old question, but just in case this helps you or someone else: the code you pasted in has org-agenda-skip-*fuction* instead of -function. =)